# iOS - How to test iPhone5C on Simulator 11.2

Tags: ios, iphone, simulator

Is there a way to test iPhone5C on Xcode 9.3 simulator? I downloaded all the simulators start from 8.2 to 11.2 but I can only see iPhone5 not iPhone5C. My app is crashing on iPhone5C and I don't have this phone and couldn't find anywhere to borrow.

Answer (score 1):

I guess iPhone 5C simulator is not present because it is the same hardware like the iPhone 5.

So just go with the iPhone 5.

Hint: It may crash because of the 32-Bit Architecture of the iPhone 5/5c (64-Bit started with iPhone 5S)

Answer (score 0):

There are few websites which offer the real devices for your testing. One of them is https://testobject.com/pricing

You will get many real devices for your testing.